# Exchange Web Services Notifications

Tags: notifications, exchangewebservices

I need to write an Exchange integration piece for my application. Whenever a contact, task, appointment, etc. gets created by ANY Exchange account on the server, I want my application to receive a notification so that it can create the equivalent object in the application.

From looking at the EWS Managed API as well as the lower-level web service API, it looks like you can only subscribe to an entire user's mailbox or a sub-folder in that mailbox. Is there any way for my application to subscribe to simply any and all mailboxes on the server?

Thank you,
Tedderz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Exchange does not support "all mailboxes" notifications. And you really do not want to subscribe to all notifications - imagine the number of notifications you will receive from 1000+ mailboxes Exchange server. 
In case of Public Folders, you cannot subsribe to the store-wide notoifcations; just the way it is architected.
ON a more general note, do not use events or notifcations for synchonization - the notifications can and are dropped under heavy loads.
There is are offcially supported API's for that (Active Sync, ICS). At best, notifcations can be used as a hint that your code must perform sync sooner rather than later.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the Exchange will bundle notifications. So if 100 events happen within a short period of time you may only receive a handful of notifications with several events in each. You would then loop through determine the event types and go from there.

Comment: I'm curious about you saying that notifications can get dropped under heavy load. As far as I know notifications are kept on the CAS for however long you please (pending on you reconnecting whenever something quirky happens) and will only get dropped if the CAS sends you a notification and you don't respond with a specific amount of time. Great answer. +1

Comment: I see. It would be a production web application server subscribing to the notifications, and not a mobile device, so that's why I didn't think the load would be prohibitively large. But if they're not reliable at all, then there's no sense in using them. I don't suppose there's a way to do blanket synchronization? It sounds like ActiveSync/ICS are for mobile devices and are still geared to one mailbox at a time.

Comment: @Tedderz: Notifications are *very* reliable so long as your application handles them correctly. If the CAS sends you a notification (push or pull) and you don't respond to it within a specific amount of time then you'll lose your subscription. Also, the term "reliable" is pretty vague considering we don't know what Dmitry's requirements are. Lastly, before you dismiss EWS notifications you should test it to see if it meets your needs.